# How can I read line by line and split every line to words ignoring white space and empty lines

Tags: c++

I have a text like this:

```
Eins zwei     Polizei

Drei vier Grenadier
Fünf Sechs Alte Hex
```

and I want to read every word using `std::istringstream` and in one row print out all the words, but for some reason some words get print out multiple times, can someone tell me why this happens and how should I do the above?
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string pom;
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        while(iss){
            iss >> pom;
            cout << pom << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

> Eins zwei Polizei Polizei Polizei Polizei Drei vier Grenadier
> Grenadier Fünf Sechs Alte Hex Hex

Expected output:

> Eins zwei Polizei Drei vier Grenadier Fünf Sechs Alte Hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this code:

```
while(iss) { 
  iss >> pom;
  // ...
}
```

After reading the last string from the stream, `while(iss)` still evaluates true, even though you can't read a string from it. So you enter the `while` loop, but `iss >> pom` fails. This leaves the last value of `pom` unchanged, and it gets printed out. This is why you see the last word printed twice on each line.

The same thing happens when the stream is initalized with an empty string. So for a blank line, the last string from the previous line gets printed out.

The correct way to write this would be:

```
while (iss >> pom) {
 cout << pom << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {


string pom;
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
       istringstream iss(line);
        while(iss){
         iss >> pom;

         // check to make sure pom isnt empty because we do not want to print out the 
         //contents when there is nothing in the string
         if (!pom.empty()){
           cout << pom << " ";

         }
         // clearing the string each time to unbuffer it, so when it
         // sees white space it will just be empty; probably a better way to do this
         pom = ""; 
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```